# split column with values inside and outside brackets python

Tags: python, string, split

I need to split (in python code) my column "code" into 2 columns:

- "outside" with value outside the brackets
- "inside" with value inside the brackets

I'd create a "prepared" column by adding a "+" separator after each letter before the number.

| id | code | outside | inside | prepared |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -(83C24H) | - | 83C24H | 83C + 24H |
| 2 | 30(30C14H) | 30 | 30C14H | 30C + 14H |
| 3 | 25 | 25 | 0 | 0 |

Thank u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df['outside'] = df['code'].str.replace(r'\([^)]*\)', '', regex=True)
df['inside'] = df['code'].str.extract(r'\(([^)]+)')

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id        code outside  inside
0   1   -(83C24H)       -  83C24H
1   2  30(30C14H)      30  30C14H
```

---

EDIT: With updated dataframe:

```py
mask = df['code'].str.contains(r'\(.*\)', regex=True)

df['inside'] = df.loc[mask, 'code'].str.extract(r'\(([^)]+)')
df['outside'] = df.loc[mask, 'code'].str.replace(r'\([^)]*\)', '', regex=True)
df['inside'] = df['inside'].fillna(df['code'])
df['outside'] = df['outside'].fillna('0')

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id        code  inside outside
0   1   -(83C24H)  83C24H       -
1   2  30(30C14H)  30C14H      30
2   3          25      25       0
```

Comment: Thank u! It seems to work! But I modified my question by introducing the case where it was just a number, without brackets. 
I also add other point... Could edit your code please?

Comment: id3 should have 25 outside, 0 inside... not 0 and 0..